# Using dictionary to display values in VIEW

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dictionary, orchardcms

Using Orchard 1.6 MVC I wanted to display a list of 'suppliers' on screen. For every supplier, display a list of their products, and the quantity remaining.

```
Supplier 1
product 101
product 102

supplier 2
product 103
product 104
product 105

etc...
```

My ViewModel

```
public class SuppliersOrderVM
    {
        public IEnumerable<SupplierInfo> SupplierInformation = new List<SupplierInfo>();
        public Dictionary<int, QBSupplierRecord> Suppliers { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, QBProductRecord> Products { get; set; }

        public SuppliersOrderVM(IEnumerable<SupplierInfo> supplierInformation, Dictionary<int, QBSupplierRecord> suppliers, Dictionary<int, QBProductRecord> products)
        {
            SupplierInformation = supplierInformation;
            Suppliers = suppliers;
            Products = products;
        }

        public class SupplierInfo
        {
            public int SupplierId { get; set; }
            public bool SendEmail { get; set; }

            public List<ProductInfo> Products = new List<ProductInfo>();
        }

        public class ProductInfo
        {
            public int ProductId { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

So in the view Ive used the dictionary to output the supplier name. But I am having trouble outputting the products for that supplier. My 2nd foreach loop may be wrong and my syntax is incorrect for displaying product.
Please help me amend it

```
 @{
foreach (var supplier in Model.SupplierInformation)
{
            <div class="editor-label">@Html.Label("SupplierName")</div>
            <div class="editor-label">@Model.Suppliers[supplier.SupplierId].CompanyName</div>

           @* <div class="editor-label">@Html.HiddenFor(s => s.SupplierInfor[0].</div>*@

    foreach (var product in Model.SupplierInformation)
    {
            //create table and output product code & product Quantity
<div class="editor-label">@Model.Products[product.Products].ProductCode</div>
```

It is telling me [product.Products] has some invalid arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but as per my understanding you are trying to display

1. `ProductCode` which is in the `QBProductRecord` class and this class is being used as part of dictionary (in which the key being used is the `ProductId`) in your model class `SuppliersOrderVM`.
2. `Quantity` which is a property in the class `Product`.

Then you should use the following code. The error in you code is that you are trying to use `product.Products` as an index which should be an integer but it's not.

```
@{
foreach (var supplier in Model.SupplierInformation)
{
            <div class="editor-label">@Html.Label("SupplierName")</div>
            <div class="editor-label">@Model.Suppliers[supplier.SupplierId].CompanyName</div>

           @* <div class="editor-label">@Html.HiddenFor(s => s.SupplierInfor[0].</div>*@

    foreach (var product in supplier.Products)
    {
            //create table and output product code & product Quantity
<div class="editor-label">@Model.Products[product.ProductId].ProductCode</div>
           //display quantity
<div class="editor-label">product.Quantity</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this line meant to do?:

```
Model.Products[product.Products]
```

If I'm following your model hierarchy correctly, `Model` is an instance of `SuppliersOrderVM`.  Which means that `Model.Products` is an instance of `Dictionary<int, QBProductRecord>`.  In order to access an element from that `Dictionary` you need to index it with an `int`.  However, `product.Products` isn't an `int`, it's a `List<ProductInfo>`.

Did you mean to add another loop for the `List<ProductInfo>`, in order to access the `ProductId` property on each element therein?  Something like this?:

```
foreach (var productInfo in product.Products)
    <div class="editor-label">@Model.Products[productInfo.ProductId].ProductCode</div>
```

It's difficult to tell exactly what you're trying to do.  The model hierarchy is a little awkward with so many things called "product."

Comment: @Model.Products[product.Products].ProductCode< is meant to output the product but I dont have the correct syntax. SupplierInformation contains the suppliers and all their products. I have accessed the suppliers ok now I need to output their products...any ideas? thanks for reply

Comment: @John: It would need to be in a loop in order to use the values from `product.Products`, as in the posted answer.  Each `SupplierInfo` object in `product` internally has a list of `ProductInfo` objects.  So you can't pass that whole list to the `Model.Products` dictionary.  You have to loop over that list and pass each ID to the dictionary.  It would probably make a lot more sense if you rename the `product` variable in your loop to `supplierInfo`, making it `foreach (var supplierInfo in Model.SupplierInformation)`, since that loop isn't iterating over products, but over suppliers.